# Cross-compile any aptitude package?

Tags: arm, packaging, chrome-book

I have an ARM Chromebook. There is a project called Crouton that is able to install Ubuntu to the internal harddrive pretty easily (I've done it).
But most packages in the repositories are of course only for X86 and X64.

1. Is it even possible technically to take an arbitrary apt package and cross-compile it to run on my ARM Chromebook?
2. If it is possible, how can I do so relatively painlessly? I have access to a very fast 24-core system for the compilation if I can figure out a way to automate the process of making ARM packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the source for any package in the apt repository. You can even download it and compile it all in one command.

There is, of course, no guarantee that something not ported to your flavor of ARM will work. Many things have x86 assembly deep in them.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
sudo apt-get source --compile <package>
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/335260).